# log information of remote login in xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp

how can i get the user log information, who accessed the system using remote login for windows XP.

Comment: Probably one for http://superuser.com/ - you might get more responses there.

Answer (score 0):

> There should be an entry in the
>   security log available via Event
>   Viewer if auditing of logon events is
>   enabled which it may be by default.
>   Look for type 10 logon events. However
>   you may need see the IP address but
>   instead the name of the computer.
>   Firewall logs [hardware or host] may
>   help track down the IP of the computer
>   if you match the logs to the time of
>   the type 10 logon event.
>
> http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Logon-Types.html
>   --- logon events explained

Link to: [Source](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-security/838814.htm#post3252200)